# How to stub a flash in a RSpec spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

In my view, I have a `hidden_field_tag` whose value is a `flash` set in the controller. In other words, the flow is as follows:

**Controller:**

```
def home
    flash[:id] = 123
end
```

**View:**

```
<% form_tag(new_invitee_path) %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :referer, flash[:id] %>
<% end %>
```

**Params submitted to new_invitee_path**:

```
{ "referer" => "123" }
```

**I can confirm that in manual testing this works appropriately, but I can't figure out how to stub appropriately.**

In my test I have:

```
before do
  #set flash
  visit '/home'
  fill_in "rest_of_form"
  click_button "submit_form
end
```

Where below are the things I've tried to do for `set flash` and the error messages I get:

```
flash[:id] = 123 
# OR
flash.now[:id] = 123 
# both render error: undefined local variable or method `flash' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fc1040f7d60>

# Have also tried a tactic found online to set flash for response object like this:
visit '/home'
response.flash[:id] = 123
# OR
response.flash.now[:id] = 123
# both render error: undefined local variable or method `response' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fe118a38490>

#Have read online that it's a problem with the flash being sweeped, so I tried to stub out the sweep, but am unclear how to set the anonymous controller or whatever correctly
controller.instance_eval{flash.stub!(:sweep)}
flash[:id] = 123 
# OR
flash.now[:id] = 123 
# renders error: undefined local variable or method `flash' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your spec is a feature spec, so the spec environment has no access to things like the flash. Don't try to work with the flash directly. Instead, ideally, test that the user's view of the app looks and/or behaves the way that it should if the flash value is set the way that it should be. I wouldn't just test that the hidden field is present in the form; I'd test that it has the effect that it should after the form is submitted. That's what feature specs are all about: testing that the application works as a whole from the user point of view.

If the flash value isn't ever used in the UI, just logged or stored in the database, it would be OK to test that the log line or model object has the value that's stored in the flash. (The user here is the admin who would look at the log or whatever later.) But if the flash does affect the UI, testing that is preferable.

Comment: ok that's fair, in which case, I'd like to set the hidden value to 123 itself so that it's passed, and I can check that it's saved into the new object. Is there a way of doing this in the RSPEC then?

Comment: Is it really just a hardcoded number? If so, just move it to a constant and reference that constant in the test. If it really comes from a method or something you could stub the method, or otherwise arrange things in the test so the method returns a number of your choice that you can assert at the end.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work pretty well for me:

```
YourController.any_instance.stub(:flash) { {some: "thing" }}
```

Comment: This works well, for controller specs at least - shame there isn't an easier way by now! Just for anyone stumbling on this, the newer syntax is `allow_any_instance_of(described_class).to receive(:flash).and_return(some: "thing")`